# Facebook and other social networking sites implementation in cordova 3.3.0

Tags: cordova-3

I am trying to integrate facebook, twitter, instagram, flickr and linkd'in login in Cordova ver-3.3.0.But I am unable to find the solution.Can anybody please help me by sharing some links or useful content.

Comment: how you are trying to integrate them ? show some code ...!

Comment: Actually I have not implemented it yet...I am just exploring it as I have to integrate in one of my app.I searched a lot but not getting how to begin.

Comment: take a look on InAppBrowser. You can open any mobile site using this, it will not use the phone's browser.
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html

Answer (score 0):

For **Facebook login** plugin try this
**http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/01/facebook-login-logout-using-cordova-330.html**.